# What issues might there be in accepting a position in the cannabis industry?

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, new-job

I might be offered a position as a software developer at a company that produces software for the cannabis industry. I don't have any legal, ethical, or moral issues with the job, company, or industry in general.

The question I have is if I take the job and then leave at some point in the future, will my resume find it's way to the HR trash can due to the industry?

If I saw a resume from somebody that worked in this industry, I don't think it would bias me against the applicant but I'm not sure if this is a common sentiment.

Comment: Whether or not this will be seen negatively will probably come down to the beliefs of the individual.

Comment: If the industry is legal in the jurisdiction where you were working for that industry, it probably wouldn't matter to liberal types... on the other hand, more conservative folks may well be biased against the association. Conversely, someone working for a weapons manufacturer may experience biased opinion from a liberal, but be totally supported by more conservative types. But we can't tell you what everyone will think about any given thing.

Comment: I don't see this causing any issues for you.  After all, you are writing software, not growing cannabis.

Comment: They just produce software for the cannabis industry or is that only part of what they do? End of the day you're not in the cannabis industry, your in the software industry, doesn't matter if your companies clients are pharmaceuticals or mafia.

Comment: @Kilisi it definitely matters if the clients are mafia, you'll probably get thrown into jail for that. but agree that bc this company sells software and not drugs it's not such an issue.

Comment: You will be permanently banned from entering the US. (Or at least until there is a change in policy)

Answer (score 2):

> The question I have is if I take the job and then leave at some point in the future, will my resume find it's way to the HR trash can due to the industry?

The short answer is that there is probably some non-zero percent chance that the association with the cannabis industry `might` hurt your prospects in a very small number of roles that you apply for.

This is probably `not` a good reason to skip out on the opportunity though.

I say this because if a company would pass solely on such a factor, then they completely ruled you out for something that has virtually no impact on your ability to perform the job. It is their loss if they want to filter on such criteria, and you might be better off avoiding a company that makes decisions like that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the answer can only be opinion based.

You could have the same doubt after accepting a position in a weapon company: someone could be scared by a new hire that may come to work with a weapon under the belt.

What about the gambling industry? Someone may think that you work there because you like betting and then discard your application.

Ever worked on some XXX site? Scared by biased opinion about that on your resume? It depends on the country, obviously.

If it is a legit job that's not against your beliefs/opinions/interest/whatever you should submit your CV.

Answer (score 1):

It might have at least a minor impact.

I'm a very liberal/progressive software engineer in a location where medical marijuana is legal and recreationals largely culturally accepted. There is even a software development firm in town that caters to firms in that industry (might even be the same one you're considering). I know people who use marijuana.

Even I would hesitate to consider an applicant who went to work in that field though and if someone like me is going to have even a mild concern, there will probably be many more who will outright condemn it.

There are a few concerns I'd have if a resume with weed experience came across my desk:

1. All else equal, why work there when other options were available to the candidate, considering that other people might look unfavourably upon it? Were they desperate? Are they unskilled?
2. Does this person get high?
3. What kind of work environment are they used to/expecting? Were their co-workers high on the job and how might that affect their work ethic?
4. Are they going to evanglise the medical benefits of weed around the office?
5. Do they take their career seriously or is this just a paycheck? I prefer to work with people who spend time improving their skills, keeping up with new developments in our field, and striving to do excellent work. If they're willing to work at a place that might tarnish their career, are they going to be spending time on the weekend keeping up with professional education or are they getting high?

Comment: if someone worked for a brewery, would you worry they are used to drinking at work? How is #2 germane to coding, or #4 a problem? I do appreciate your candor though, kudos and +1 for that.

Comment: Most of them are non sense... So if I worked on a software producing sex toys HR would think "does this person use them at work?" "Are they going to evangeilse the benefit of sex toys around the office?"

Comment: If I designed software for a spa company, would you assume I spend my weekends lying back in a chair with cucumbers on my eyes listening to a harp?

Comment: 1. Long-term us of sex toys isn't going to damage knowledge a worker's cognitive abilities. So I really don't care if they use them or not outside of work.

Comment: 2. The nature of the concerns (not assumptions) about a candidate are not simple "worked in industry X therefore might use X's product". If you worked for the NRA, I'm going to wonder if you're a gun fanatic. If you worked for Uber, I'm going to be concerned that you're a sexual preditor.

Comment: "If you worked for Uber, I'm going to be concerned that you're a sexual preditor." - at this point, I think your viewpoint is becoming irrelevant.  You seem willing to hold almost any background against a potential employee, so your opinion about one who worked in the cannabis industry as a software developer seems to be one part of a more general dislike, rather than relevant to the question.